# Creating an Array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino

I have two int values:

```
v_y
v_x
```

That I would like to convert to a size 2 char array then write to my serial port.

I currently have this code that isn't working:

```
void Array2 (char charArray[], int sizeOfArray);



........

                        }
                        {
                            char  one[] = { 'v_x', 'v_y' };
                            Array2(one, 2);
                            Serial::WriteData(one, 2);
                        }
                    }
```

I currently get two errors:

> a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object

and

> 'Serial::WriteData':illegal call of non-static member function.

Any help, hint or idea on what I'm doing wrong would be great!

Edit: I'm using this code to communicate with my serialport  [CODE](https://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/CPPWindows/)

Comment: The error message looks like it has nothing to do with your array.  Also, `v_x` isn't a `char`, it's a `char const*` (if you're not getting a warning about this, crank up your compiler's warning level).

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: I'm using this code for my Arduino to communicate with my C++ code, [CODE](https://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/CPPWindows/)

Comment: Ok, but, do you mean that you want to transmit the strings "v_x" and "v_y" or do you want to transmit the value of two variables named v_x and v_y?

Comment: Sorry if my question wasn't clear, I want to transmit the value of the two variables named v_x and v_y

Comment: @HereForBigHelp And do you want to pass it like text (eg. "100.0"), or like raw data?

Comment: @Lasersköld, I posted the wrapper for my Arduino, I think I would need the raw data right?

Comment: Ok, I think i got it right this time. I think the safest is to pack it in a struct like in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cpp
// data.h or similar, you need this for both the arduino and desktop machine
struct Data {
   double v_x;
   double v_y;
}
```

On your arduino: To write

```cpp
Data data = {
   .v_x = 1.0, // Example put your values here
   .v_y = 2.0,
};

// This should write from your Arduino to the computer
Serial::WriteData((const char*)data, sizeof(data));
```

On your computer

```cpp
Data data;

// This reads from the serial port, and put the data in the struct
auto len = SP->ReadData((const char*)data, sizeof(data));

// check that data is the right size
// use the data from data.v_x and data.v_y

auto v_x = data.v_x;
auto v_y = data.v_y; // etc
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful!

Comment: Happy to help :)